# nix-build not found inside nix-shell (Linux)

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, nix-shell

Every time I enter `nix-shell`, I need to execute the following command, otherwise `nix-build` and other `nix-*` commands are not found.

```
source /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
```

I have added the following into file `~/.profile`, but it does not seem to be working.

```
if [ -e /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh ]; then source /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh; fi # added by Nix installer
```

What's the reason for that? How can I get `source /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh` automatically when I run `nix-shell`?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].
Also, this seems to be a nix question rather than a Cardano question and it should not be on this site if that is the case.

Comment: This is fairly odd and should not happen. `nix-shell` would know how to set your profile. So what you are saying is it works in your regular shell, but fails in `nix-shell`. Can you please provide more info around the context? What system do you run on, ...?

Comment: Yes, context information is going to be essential to find the problem here. Perhaps the shell is overwritting the PATH a bit too aggresively. If you have a link or a relevant snippet from the shell.nix, please share

Comment: Thanks @nrdxp! I'm running on Ubuntu, I run `shell.nix` from [plutus-apps](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/shell.nix), should I change the this file somehow?

Comment: Hi @gRebel, I had this problem when I run `plutus-apps` for plutus pioneer program.

Comment: If it is a generic nix problem, it shoudn't be here.  If nix is fine and the problem is with the `plutus-apps` package, then it might be relevant here is if it fits the [help/on-topic] on-topic criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the plutus playground environment to run properly until I followed the directions in this link https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/Ubuntu.html and first did the uninstall at the bottom of the page and did the re-install (as explained on the same page from the link provided above) for multiple-user. The multi-user version is recommended on the actual Nix website.  When I got to this line "Note If you will be working on the Plutus Pioneer Project, it will be necessary at this point to git checkout ... a specific commit to match the class materials. That commit hash is listed in the exercises week## directory in the cabal.project", I followed along with the tutorial listed below to compile the "English Auction" code from week01:  https://youtu.be/zPaDp4R9X7o?t=177  Your folders might vary from the instructors, so listen carefully to where you clone the repositories he mentions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the specific commit for the repo, like I said everything works after I do `source /home/xxx/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh` each time entering `nix-shell`. I believe the path environment somehow is overwritten incorrectly after `nix-shell`, but don't know where to change it.

Comment: Perhaps related, I think I must have installed Nix twice, or a build or shell, still learning, but I think I created two different profile-link-1 and profile-link-2 in the directory /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/<username>.  When I do a `nix doctor --verbose` I was getting a multiple versions fail (https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/nix-doctor-verbose-fail-multiple-versions-of-nix-found-in-path-on-macos-i7). Maybe someone smarter than me can help on how this happens, and if linked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).