# nix doctor --verbose [FAIL] Multiple versions of nix found in PATH, on MacOS i7

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, macos

After performing a git commit tag update on plutus-apps, I restarted my computer, and ran `nix doctor --verbose` and got the following FAIL

```
  [FAIL] Multiple versions of nix found in PATH:
    /nix/store/iq3ra93h9kxmnrw3zlxmqn8ng5w62dra-nix-2.5.1/bin
    /nix/store/j6fqvmsfhl4frzqn2f3bzhn8hr16j5q5-nix-2.5.1/bin
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Updates on troubleshooting:
1. performed nix install `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon`
2. read up on nix-store documentation 
3. performed `nix-store --delete /nix/store/j6fqvmsfhl4frzqn2f3bzhn8hr16j5q5-nix-2.5.1/bin` to delete both instances, got "error: Cannot delete path /nix/store/... since it is still alive.  To find out why, use: nix-store --query --roots.

Comment: I may have created two profiles in /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/<username> as profile-link-1 and profile-link-2, potentially two different user environments.  I may have done something twice and nix made two different user env rather than overrride. See https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/introduction.html?highlight=%2Fnix%2Fvar%2Fnix%2Fprofiles%2Fper-user%2F#multi-user-support

Answer (score 0):

I had success with just fully **uninstalling nix**.

However, uninstalling nix wasn't straight forward either (surprise!).  From my research, here are options that worked.

**How to uninstall nix**:

1. Script [Github kintsugi/uninstall-nix-osx.sh](https://gist.github.com/kintsugi/47e5e9f9d7c3a3a2f6004b6271365f8c)

   - (hat tip to the tutorial https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md, see very bottom)
   - from terminal, cd to desktop (or whatever is easiest)
   - `git clone https://gist.github.com/47e5e9f9d7c3a3a2f6004b6271365f8c.git`
   - in terminal, `sudo sh <drag-and-drop-file-here>` or `sudo sh </path/to/file/and_file_here>`

OR

2. Manually follow [Github Issue, How to remove nix #1402](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1402#issuecomment-312496360)

   - I did this just as backup, #1 already worked, although there were some caution statements.
3. **RESTART COMPUTER**
4. In new tab, in ~/plutus-apps directory

   - `nix doctor --verbose` now all passes!

So far, the nix-build, nix-shell have worked too...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).